# Setting Cookie from react not find in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies in server side

Tags: c#, reactjs, cookies, model-view-controller, redux-saga

I try to use in saga.js function:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

export function* certLoginFlow() {
  while (true) {
...
var expiresDate = new Date();
expiresDate.setTime(expiresDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 90); //90 day
 yield call(certificateLogin, { data });
...
}
}
```

// Set the cookie:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('CryptoProVersion', version, { path: '/', expires: expiresDate });
```

// Try to get in web-api controller:

```
  public static string ExtractCryptoInfo(HttpRequestBase request)
        {
            var Cookies = request.Cookies;

            if (Cookies != null && Cookies["CryptoProVersion"] != null)
            {
                return Cookies["CryptoProVersion"].Value;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

ExtractCryptoInfo always return null..Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Ok, I think It's must be like this, but still not working:

```
export function postRequest(url, data, cookies) {
  return fetch(url,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Set-Cookie': cookies
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON);
}
```

I also use CORS..

Comment: Hi, @Kseniya, can you confirm the cookie has been correctly set, maybe using `Dev Tools > Applications Tab > Storage > Cookies` in Chrome? Another thing to consider: I'm not familiar with your C# server side, but how exactly does it get the info that you set in the cookie? Are you sending it to the server somehow? Or does the server get it automatically?

Comment: Hi :) I think It's must change postRequest method.. Update question.